# Mysql Java Derby Netbeans: 'deleteRow' not allowed because the ResultSet is not an updatable ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc, derby

I'm trying delete a row but it does not allow me, it says "'deleteRow' not allowed because the ResultSet is not an updatable ResultSet". Here is my code:

```
public void addUserName() throws SQLException {
    rs = st.executeQuery("select NAME, prize from usernames");
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            String attribute2 = rs.getString("name");

            if (attribute2.equals(getName())){
                String toPrint = rs.getString(2);
                System.out.println("Welcome back " + getName());
                System.out.println("You previously won " + toPrint);
                System.out.println("Let's see if you can do any better this time :)");
                rs.deleteRow();

            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Millionaire.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any advise would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is how I created the table, and added the advise given, but still getting the same error:

```
public void createTable(String tableName) {
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                              ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        //String newTable = "millionair";

        //statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists "+newTable);
        String sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (NAME VARCHAR(50), PRIZE INT)";

        stmt.executeUpdate(sqlCreateTable);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

> **A default ResultSet object is not updatable** and has a cursor that
>   moves forward only. Thus, you can iterate through it only once and
>   only from the first row to the last row. It is possible to produce
>   ResultSet objects that are scrollable and/or updatable. The following
>   code fragment, in which con is a valid Connection object, illustrates
>   how to make a result set that is scrollable and insensitive to updates
>   by others, and that is updatable. See ResultSet fields for other
>   options.

```
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
                                  ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b FROM TABLE2");
   // rs will be scrollable, will not show changes made by others,
   // and will be updatable
```

So you have to set `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` property when creating a statement.

Comment: I tried your advise but got the same error, maybe the problem is with the way I create the table? Can you check my edit please.

Comment: @almostabeginner where is `st` variable initialized which you use in `addUserName()` you have to place `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` on that `st` variable not in  `stmt` variable initialization

Comment: I initialized st in the constructor of my database class, I did it right after establishing mysql connection. Ohhh, that would make sense lol, I think this should work, one second please.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly, and thanks for the reading material, it helps a lot with the understanding parts of it.